# How to get JSON array in PHP and print its value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

Actually I have created an array that contains table rows value and I want to pass the array to PHP file using jQuery and I want to store it in MySql database.

I have done as:

```
var myTableArray = [];

$("table#tbl-nitem tr").each(function() {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function() {
            arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text());
        });

        alert(arrayOfThisRow);
        arrayOfThisRow.shift();
        myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
});
//myTableArray.shift();
alert(myTableArray);

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myTableArray);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "script_expenses.php",
    data: {
        data: jsonString
    },
    cache: false,

    success: function(response) {
        if (response == "ok") {
            alert("OK");
        } else {
            alert(response);
        }
    }
});
```

The above code that will create, store and pass the array to .php file

```
$conn = require_once 'db_connection.php';
//echo $conn;
session_start();
$data = $_GET['data'];
json_encode($data);

//  $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table ( fname, lname ) VALUES ( ?,? )"; 
//$ins = 

$sql = "INSERT INTO expenses_list VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);

foreach($data as $row) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss', 'TEA');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss', $row['Purpose']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss', $row['UnitPrice']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss', $row['Qty']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss', $row['DTime']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss', $row['Description']);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

flush();
```

The above code will receive the array and try to store in databse.
But I am getting an error in foreach statement as: 
**Invalid argument supplied foreach**

I searched and come to know that the receiving value is not an array.
How to solve the issue???

Comment: You should use [`json_decode($data)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead of `json_encode($data)`.

Comment: you should use `$data = json_decode($_GET['data']);`

Comment: $data = json_decode($_GET['data'],true);

Comment: The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement.

Comment: hi, 
That error is resolved now but I am getting more errors as
mysqli_stmt_bind_param expects paramater 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string

Comment: yes you have more error that is what i answered in my below answer check it @JSalaria

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param first argument is $stmt . you missed that . add it .@JSalaria

Comment: number of (?) question marks match with number variable otherwise it will give this error . check you statement  @JSalaria

Comment: Same error as i mentioned in my last error comment...
Its really very disgusting

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
$data = $_GET['data'];

$data = json_decode($data,true);
```

now you can use $data in foreach loop
**Update 1**

```
$conn =  require_once'db_connection.php';
session_start();
$data = $_GET['data'];
$data = json_decode($data,true);

$sql    = "INSERT INTO expenses_list VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt   = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql);

foreach($data as $row){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', 'TEA');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row['Purpose']);

    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row['UnitPrice']);
    //if UnitPrice is double values then use
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('d', $row['UnitPrice']);

    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row['Qty']);
    //if Qty is integer then use
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('i', $row['Qty']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row['DTime']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row['Description']);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

In mysqli_stmt_bind_param please use following types

i   corresponding variable has type integer

d   corresponding variable has type double

s   corresponding variable has type string

b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

for more refernce check this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Hi, Tried but the nature of error is same as mysqli_stmt_bind_param expects paramater 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string

Comment: Hey J Salaria, I think your not adding correct type please check the update 1 answer

Comment: You are right, I have gone through the link and update my code and still getting the same error

Comment: okay `echo $_GET['data'];` and let me know what is the output

Comment: As, I am adding... TEA, OFFICE, 1, 3, 20/MAY/2017-14:46, EVENING, 3 and I am getting as [["TEA","OFFICE","1","3","20/MAY/2017-14:46","EVENING","3"]]

Comment: If its is working for you guys plz share Fiddle link

Comment: Hi, Here I am getting 1 extra value and I dont want to bind that and that's I did not use a bind statement for the last value... This may be the cause of error.. I am just checking this... lets C

Comment: if i json_deocde it [["TEA","OFFICE","1","3","20/MAY/2017-14:46","EVENING","3"]] i am getting index array Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => TEA [1] => OFFICE [2] => 1 [3] => 3 [4] => 20/MAY/2017-14:46 
based on your answer change the code as mentioned below 
`foreach($data as $row){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', 'TEA');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row[1]);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('i', $row[2]);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('i', $row[3]);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row[4]);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row[5]);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}`

Comment: Boss, I have also tried this but the error is same. Why not to create JSFiddle and share the link

Answer (score 0):

use **json_decode()**  set second parameter **true** When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['data'],true);
```

Note : read the documentation your code have lots of error [prepared statement](http://php.chinaunix.net/manual/hu/function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param.php)

1) The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement. you put double **ss** for each variable .

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $row['Purpose']); //remove one s because your binding one variable only
```

2) Binds **variables** to a prepared statement as parameters not accept **string**

`$tea ='TEA';
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('s', $tea);`

variable should be passed by reference to bind parameter . not accept string .

3) mysqli_stmt_bind_param first argument is **$stmt** . you missed that . add it .

4) number of (?) question marks match with number bind variable otherwise it will give error .

5)

```
i   corresponding variable has type integer

d   corresponding variable has type double

s   corresponding variable has type string

b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

**Update 1 :**

```
        $tea ='TEA';
    foreach($data as $row){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $tea); // s denotes   corresponding variable has type string
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $row['Purpose']);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $row['UnitPrice']);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $row['Qty']);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $row['DTime']);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $row['Description']);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried but i got no success, still the nature of error is same as mysqli_stmt_bind_param expects paramater 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string

Comment: yes missed to pass the statement . check my update answer in my update 1 @JSalaria

Comment: I also tried but I got error as 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables does not match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: number of (?) question  marks match with number variable otherwise it will give this error . check you statement

Answer (score 0):

Convert json to array. Use below code

```
$datajson = $_GET['data'];
$dataarray = json_decode($datajson, true);
```